# Notification for a reviewer

Tags: support, review-queues, notifications

I was wondering if I did a review on a e.g. low-quality post without leaving a comment around and somehow the OP figured that out, would the OP be able to notify me with the usual `@username` syntax or would that go unnoticed in this scenario?

The OP could easily figure out that I also reviewed the post if at least one of the reviewers leaves an auto or non-auto comment. Then, the OP would go to that user's profile, go to the activity tab and look for the review activity in question.

Comment: I think that goes unnoticed unless you choose to edit. That puts your name in the revision history and those users are ping-able together with commenters on the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment @-notifications can be used to notify:

- post authors
- other commenters
- editors
- "diamond" moderators who have closed the post

For more details, see: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020)

Comment: I thought it works for dupehammer-closers too, at least on one occasion they appeared to be notified by my comment. (And the page you linked to says so.)

Comment: @Behaviour: it does work for the motley stuff, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

No, `@lpapp` in a comment on a post you have only reviewed would not notify you. See [the Markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply):

> You can use the same method to notify any editor of the post, or – if this is the case – to the ♦ moderator who closed the question.

Also, see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020). There is not a provision on either of those posts for pinging a reviewer.