# How to let reviewer know they accepted a wrong edit?

Tags: support, review-queues, edits

I just came againt [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749346/dynamic-usage-of-attribute-in-recipe)

My first idea while answering is that there's an attribute missing to the first resource, wrote my answer in this way (plus other side effects).

I don't really know why but I feel it could be interesting to see the edits made to the question after and I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7758950)

The idea from the first editor is great, indenting the code block for readability, but he probably think the code inside was a try to format and removed it.

This is conflicting with author intent (and this is changing the code in an error) but it has been accepted.

I  re-edited to add the missing attribute and edited my answer.

My question is could we/should we warn the editor and the reviewers they made a mistake ?

To be more precise: is a feature like git blame something that have been already discussed ?

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281057/notification-for-a-reviewer) about notifications.

Comment: Thank @Joe didn't think searching about notification, searched about edit/review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot 'notify' a reviewer, though you can do so to an editor.

This happens from time to time in the [sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sas) tag which I frequent; people close or edit questions harmfully because they don't know SAS.  When that happens, I:

- Rollback the edit or vote to re-open
- Leave a (general) comment letting people know why the edit/close is incorrect

That's about all you can do.  Under a very few circumstances you could flag for a moderator, but it wouldn't be for one edit: only for a particular person who frequently made bad edits or bad reviews that you notice a substantial pattern.

Comment: Ok, I had an idea about a git blame thing, but indeed a comment would be enough to let the editor know he's mistake there.